# How do I stop a form from submitting?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to I stop a form from submitting? 
I have some validation on my form, and if the the input isn't correct, then the form should't submit...
In my HTML i have this when clicking submit:

```
<a href="#" onclick="setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form_4').submit()}, 1000);" style="position:static" class="btn-more">Vælg</a>
```

And the my script looks like this:

```
$("#form_4 a.btn-more").click(function (e) {

    //Validate required fields
    for (i = 0; i < required.length; i++) {
        var input = $('#' + required[i]);

        if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
            input.addClass("needsfilled");
            input.val(emptyerror);
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        } else {
            input.removeClass("needsfilled");
        }
    }
    //if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
    if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        errornotice.hide();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Add a handler to `setTimeout` and the clear the time out later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
e.preventDefault();
```

before closing the click function or at start

```
$("#form_4 a.btn-more").click(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();  
    //rest of the content
}
```

You should also change the `setTimeout function` as the way you have done it, it would always submit the form. Change to :

HTML :

```
<a href="#" style="position:static" class="btn-more">Vælg</a>
```

Script :

```
$("#form_4 a.btn-more").click(function (e) {

    //Validate required fields
    for (i = 0; i < required.length; i++) {
        var input = $('#' + required[i]);

        if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
            input.addClass("needsfilled");
            input.val(emptyerror);
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        } else {
            input.removeClass("needsfilled");
        }
    }
    //if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
    if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        return false;
    } else {
        errornotice.hide();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use javascript functions with the HTML inline. Put all of your JS on a js file.

Then, use your if like this

```
 if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) 
    {
        return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        errornotice.hide();
        $("#form_4").submit()
    }
```

Just call form submit when everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="return false";
```

This will prevent from being submitted.

> **`return false`** from within a jQuery event handler is effectively the
>   same as calling both **`e.preventDefault`** and **`e.stopPropagation`** on the
>   passed jQuery.Event object.

or

```
$("#form_4 a.btn-more").click(function (e) {
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the line

```
errornotice.hide();
return true;
```

remove return true; and add the line

```
document.getElementById('form_4').submit();
```

or

```
$(".form4").submit();
```

and remove the onlick function from a link tag

```
<a href="#"  style="position:static" class="btn-more">Vælg</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".form4").on("submit", function () {
});
```

if the value return false, this is not submitting